# Using an object type as input for a method

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I have a setting class that stores an `Object` for the data. Is there some way I can make a method to return the data in the object type/class specified? e.g.

```
public objType getData(ObjType objType) {
    objType out = (objType) data;
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Class<YourClass>.cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-).

A method may be like this (exceptions avoided in this piece of code sample):

```
public <T> T getData(Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a setting class that stores an `Object` for the data.

If you have a choice, consider not doing that. Instead, perhaps you could parameterize your class:

```
public class YourClass<T> {
    private T data;

    public void setData(T d) {
        this.data = d;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

Then someone using your class to story `Thingy` instance would use it like this:

```
YourClass<Thingy> yc = new YourClass<>();
yc.setData(new Thingy());
Thingy t = yc.getData();
```

---

If you *don't* have a choice, then casting is the (distant) second best option; [Luiggi has you covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30107826/157247).